# Android. In a client-server application, when a message is posted from a client, it is duplicated

Tags: android, rest, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I'm writing a client-server application for Android. I have a problem and I can not track it. The point is this:
I have an API method. I send a POST request from the device (however, since I use the REQUEST array on the server, the method is indifferent, and I tried to use the same GET) using Retrofit 2. The method assumes posting the message on the forum. As a result, it is placed twice, with time coinciding up to a second. I take a request from the logs and send it from the browser, the user agent displayed such as on the device, everything works correctly - only one post is published.

Retrofit method:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/index.php?m=topic&action=send")
Observable<ApiResponse> sendPost(@Field("id_topic") long id,
                                 @Field("subject") String subject,
                                 @Field("message") String text);
```

Method call:

```
public void sendPost(String subj, String text) {
    Subscription subscription = model.sendPost(args.getLong("topic_id"), subj,
            text)
            .subscribe(new Observer<ApiResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    try {
                        Log.e("Post wrong", "Error while posted message: " + e.getMessage());
                        activityCallback.makeToast("Message not published, an error occurred");
                    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
                        Log.e("Error:", "getMessaage() or activityCallback is null");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(ApiResponse apiResponse) {

                    try{
                        activityCallback.makeToast("Message successfully published");
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        Log.e("Error:", "activityCallback is null");
                    }
                    reload();
                }
            });
    addSubscription(subscription);
}
```

onClick:

```
@OnClick(R.id.sendButton)
public void send() {
    if (sendText.getText() == null
            || sendText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
        makeToast("Введите текст публикации");
        return;
    }
    presenter.sendPost("Re: Тестовая тема", sendText.getText().toString());
}
```

onClick is called exactly exactly once. In the logs looked - the request is sent the same way once. What could be the problem?
Please, help

Comment: could you post the code of the `addSubscription(subscription)` method too?

Comment: I solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe someday it will help someone. I wrote code at the very beginning of the development of this application to see the server's response in the logs:

```
// Trace serve response
    clientBuilder.interceptors().add(chain -> {
        Request request = chain.request();
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        Log.i("ServerResponse: ", response.body().string());
        return chain.proceed(request);
    });
```

As can be seen from the code, from here flew one more request, which I could not find in any way all this time. I was not attentive, I thank everyone who thought about my problem.